# Apk file doesn't load image in device

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2

I am newbie in sencha. I can create apk file using sencha cmd. In chrome,app load image. But in device,app doesn't show image.
Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Please be more specific..no one can understand your problem.

Comment: I create sencha project using sencha touch 2 and phonegap. When I run project in browser,image can be displayed, but after I convert project to apk file, image can not be displayed in device.
Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: where do you load the images from? what format of images do you use to display? how do you display it, through `CSS` or `HTML`? etc. Give us more details so we can better understand your issue and can more effectively help.

Comment: Images loaded in panel with code
  xtype: 'image',
  src: '/Marex/resources/img/acc_logo.png',

In browser,image can be load,but in apk file image can't be load.
Can you help me?
Thanks